# Using auditied in a rails4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-audited

I am working on a rails4 app and trying to use audited gem to save logs. I have followed the instructions on the github page and the audited table is created. but I put 'audited :allow_mass_assignment => true' in one of my models and restarted the server. But the audits table is still empty after updating a record of that model successfully.

Comment: When you say "trying to update" do you mean that you successfully updated it, or that it failed to update?

Comment: Successfully updated

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information (like some code samples). However, I don't think you would need `:allow_mass_assignment => true` if you are using Rails 4 and StrongParameters.